# Ffmpeg screen tear

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, manjaro

Screen tear issue in ffmpeg on manjaro linux, [View this](https://youtu.be/Fna3dgpwlyM)

ffmpeg command used-
`ffmpeg -y -f x11grab  -s 1366x768 -i :0.0  out.mkv`

```
ffmpeg -version  

ffmpeg version n4.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libjack --enable-libmfx --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

```
uname -a

Linux manjaro 5.4.2-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Dec 5 09:55:57 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Desktop environment is Budgie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was not caused by ffmpeg but by the compositor.I replaced the compositor with picom.

Answer (score 0):

FFmpeg isn't the culprit but rather the broken architecture of X.Org, X11 is such a old protocol that it doesn't fit today's needs.